# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections in Spring JPA JNDI example

Tags: spring, jndi

I am using **Spring + Spring Data JPA using JNDI** example. In this example I've developed the test case which calls one JPA Method, when I execute that I see the following error

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1858)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1835)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1815)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:899)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2522)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2508)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2338)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2333)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1269)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:264)
    at com.transcelerate.common.jpa.repository.DemoTest.testgetStudyUserRolesBySite(JPATest.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

**JPADemoTest.java**

```
public class JPADemoTest {
    private static EntityManager em = null;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
        if (em == null) {
            em = (EntityManager) Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistenceUnit").createEntityManager();
        }
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void testgetStudyUserRolesBySite(){
        String queryStr = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";  // This will be our native Jpa

        TypedQuery<StudentEntity> query = em.createQuery(queryStr, StudentEntity.class);

        List<StudentEntity> entities = query.getResultList();

        if(entities != null){
            System.out.println("Size : "+entities.size());
            for (UserRoleMapEntity userRoleMapEntity : entities) {
                StudentEntity studentEntity = userRoleMapEntity.getUserProfile();
                System.out.println("FIRSTNAME : "+studentEntity.getFirstName());
                System.out.println("LASTNAME  : "+studentEntity.getLastName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**application-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop  http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd         http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa  http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="com.common.google.jpa.transactionManager" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.common.google.jpa" />

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.common.google.jpa.repository,com.common.google.jpa.repository.custom"
                      transaction-manager-ref="com.common.google.jpa.transactionManager" />

    <bean id="com.common.google.database.transcelerateDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:XXX/datasources/Test" />
    </bean> 
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="com.common.google.jpa.transactionManager" 
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
          p:entityManagerFactory-ref="com.common.google.jpa.entityManagerFactory" />

    <bean id="com.common.google.jpa.entityManagerFactory" 
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
          p:dataSource-ref="com.common.google.database.transcelerateDataSource"
          p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="vendorAdapter">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="com.common.google.jpa.persistenceUnit"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="vendorAdapter" 
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" 
          p:database="ORACLE" 
          p:showSql="true" />
</beans>
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>com.common.google.jpa.entity.StudentEntity</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />    
            <property name="hibernate.listeners.envers.autoRegister" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="20" />
            <property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.order_updates" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: did you find a solution please?

Comment: I had have make this working. I've uploaded tutorials on https://github.com/JavaNeed/spring-mvc-jndi. You kindly take a look at here. I think both project works.

Comment: thank u for this code

Comment: Please upvote the  questions